# Spring Boot 3.1.2 security filter chain called twice when return type is reactive

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

When a reactive type (e.g. `Mono<T>`) is returned from a Spring Boot 3.1.2 web MVC controller the security filter chain is called twice, once before the API method is called and then again afterwards.

This does not happen when the return type is non-reactive.

To reproduce, here's a minimal reproducible example:

1. Use Spring Initialzr to create a Spring Boot 3.1.2 project including web, webflux and security dependencies.
2. Add a custom filter that just logs:

   ```java
   public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

     @Override
     public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
       throws IOException, ServletException {

       logger.info("Custom filter called");
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add a security filter chain bean to add the filter:

   ```java
   @Configuration
   public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Bean
     public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
       return http.build();
     }
   }
   ```
4. Add a REST API for testing:

   ```java
   @RestController
   public class RestApi {

     @GetMapping("/hello-reactive")
     Mono<String> helloReactive() {
       return Mono.just("hello world");
     }

     @GetMapping("/hello")
     String hello() {
       return "hello world";
     }
   }
   ```

Now we can show the issue:

First the non-reactive method:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/hello
hello world
```

Logging:

```
2023-08-11T10:30:02.232+01:00  INFO 24000 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.example.demo.CustomFilter            : Custom filter called
```

Now the reactive method:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/hello-reactive
hello world
```

Logging:

```
2023-08-11T10:32:12.776+01:00  INFO 24000 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] com.example.demo.CustomFilter            : Custom filter called
2023-08-11T10:32:12.779+01:00  INFO 24000 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] com.example.demo.CustomFilter            : Custom filter called
```

Comment: Are you expecting the server to be a reactive application or a servlet application.

Comment: This is a traditional servlet-based application. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-methods/return-types.html) states that reactive types may be used as return values and that they are broadly equivalent to `DeferredResult`. Reactive return values are particularly handy when you're passing back the result of a `WebClient` call. This all works, but the security filter chain shouldn't be called twice.

Answer (score 0):

To not to let above security customFilter apply twice, you can simply permit all for async dispatcher in SecurityFilterChain. With this setting only request dispatcher will apply customFilter.

```
 .... 
 http
     .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer -> {
       authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer
           .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ASYNC).permitAll()
           ...
     });
```

The below github issue may be interesting to read for other alternatives: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11962

Alternatively adding securty context repository to the request filter and saving context is better because it will then check again but as it is already set as authenticated, it wont execute authentication twice.

```
RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository requestAttributeSecurityContextRepository = new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository();
            SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
            securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
            requestAttributeSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(securityContext, request, response);
```